# Azure AD Group- Authorization_RequestDenied - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I’m trying to create the Azure AD Group using the following terraform code through the Azure DevOps.

```
# Create Azure AD Group in Active Directory for AKS Admins
resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators" {
  #name        = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name}-administrators"
  display_name        = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name}-${var.environment}-administrators"
  description = "Azure AKS Kubernetes administrators for the ${azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name}-${var.environment} cluster."
  security_enabled = true
}
```

I have followed these steps to provide the permission to create Azure AD Groups through the Azure DevOps ARM service connection (Service Principle).

•   Provide permission for Service connection created in previous step to create Azure AD Groups

•   Go to -> Azure DevOps -> Select Organization -> Select project terraform-azure-aks

•   Go to Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Service Connections

•   Open terraform-aks-azurerm-svc-con

•   Click on Manage Service Principal, new tab will be opened

•   Click on View API Permissions

•   Click on Add Permission

•   Select an API: Microsoft APIs

•   Commonly used Microsoft APIs: Supported legacy APIs: Azure Active Directory Graph-DEPRECATING Use Microsoft Graph

•   Click on Application Permissions

•   Check Directory.ReadWrite.All and click on Add Permission

•   Click on Grant Admin consent for Default Directory

But I’m getting the following error:

> Error: Creating group "xxxxxxxxxx-administrators"
> │
> │   with azuread_group.aks_administrators,
> │   on 06-aks-administrators-azure-ad.tf line 2, in resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators":
> │    2: resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators" {
> │
> │ graphrbac.GroupsClient#Create: Failure responding to request:
> │ StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
> │ error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error"
> │ Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2022-01-25T04:06:31","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient
> │ privileges to complete the
> │ operation."}}}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the ***Microsoft Graph permission `Directory.ReadWrite.All`*** has been ***provided to the service connection and it has been granted the admin consent***.

I tested the same in my environment where I ***gave the permission to my service principal but didn't grant admin consent*** like below :

[image]

[image]

***When deploying the below code, it gave me error :***

```
provider "azuread" {}
# Create Azure AD Group in Active Directory for AKS Admins
resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators" {
  #name        = "ans-aks-administrators"
  display_name        = "ans-aks-test-administrators"
  description = "Azure AKS Kubernetes administrators for the ans-aks-test cluster."
  security_enabled = true
}
```

[image]

***After granting the permission admin consent it gets resolved :***

[image]

[image]

---

***If the issue still occurs then please add a new secret for the service connection service principal and use the below code :***

```
provider "azuread" {
client_id = "ClientID of the service principal"
client_secret = "ClientSecret"
tenant_id = "<TenantID>"
}

# Create Azure AD Group in Active Directory for AKS Admins
resource "azuread_group" "aks_administrators" {
  #name        = "ans-aks-administrators"
  display_name        = "ans-aks-test-administrators"
  description = "Azure AKS Kubernetes administrators for the ans-aks-test cluster."
  security_enabled = true
}
```

Comment: AnsumanBal, still I'm getting same error.

Comment: @Pradeep , can you please provide the screenshot of the service connection and its api permissions that you have provided

Comment: What do we do when we can't alter the permissions via that workflow? I am the Owner of my subscription, but there is a parent group above me. "Grant Admin Consent" is greyed out, and I cannot edit the MS Graph API permissions. What are my options? How does my parent organization configure my subscription so this isn't an issue? Isn't "Owner" as high as I can go?